# How to config CDT debug for cygwin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am new to eclipse CDT with cygwin. I just created a HelloWorld C++ project.

1. The built exe works in cygwin.
2. If I click the exe in file in file explorer, it says that it can not find cygwin1.dll. This error can be resolved by adding C:\cygwin64\bin to the Path env variable.
3. If I try to debug directly, I got the following errors:

Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Error creating process /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/C:/Users/Cheng_g15klso/Documents/Proj/HelloWorld/C:/Users/Cheng_g15klso/Documents/Proj/HelloWorld/Debug/HelloWorld.exe, (error 2).

The above diagnosis seems to point to lacking of C:\cygwin64\bin, so I add C:\cygwin64\bin to Path env variable in the env var tab of the debug config, but the result is the same.

My questions:

1. How to solve this issue?
2. Where to find a list of error to decode error 2?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the latest gdb above version 9.2-1 is wrong: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1105969/

I have downgrade my gdb and gcc for cgywin to cure the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @CPW, Then you are saying that cygwin-gdb 9-2.1 (and earlier - I've the same problem with version 12.1-1) has bugs, because Eclipse under Linux runs correctly with all gdb version till 13.2-1 ...  The issue in the question seems more an eclipse-cdt path configuration issue!